# AS3 Having difficulty getting movieclips to stay on top over other clips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, movieclip

So I have 5 movieclips on screen that when clicked (DOWN state) expand. They all come to the top of the screen because of this code:

```
addChildAt(this.Step0btn,1);
addChildAt(this.Step1btn,1);
addChildAt(this.Step2btn,1);
addChildAt(this.Step3btn,1);
addChildAt(this.Step4btn,1);
```

My issue is that on each of the expanded movieclips is another movieclip that also expands, but when I click that it still displays underneath everything else. I thought I could just add another addChildAt command like:

```
addChildAt(this.Step0btn.Step0img,1);
```

But when I do that I get this error:

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at SMARTTTraining_fla::MainTimeline/SMARTTTraining_fla::frame5()[SMARTTTraining_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:14]

And then the expanded movieclip still displays underneath everything. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Step0img` is `null` when that line of code runs. Likely explaination could be that `Step0img` doesn't exist on the frame that `Step0Btn` is on.

For your layering issue (and your error I suppose too),  this would be what you'd want to do:

```
this.addChild(Step0btn);
```

OR

```
this.setChildIndex(Step0btn,this.numChildren-1);
```

They do the same thing.  This will bring to the foremost layer above the other step buttons, you don't want to change parent/child relationship by doing `addChild(step0btn.step0img);`

If you are using the same code that I provided in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064851/as3-how-to-make-only-1-movieclip-clickable-at-a-time-when-there-are-multiple-mov), this is what the `onPress` method would look like now:

```
function onPress(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // toggle between frame 1 and 3 on button press
    gotoAndStop(Step0btn.currentFrame == 3 ? 1 : 3); //this expands your button presumably
    parent.addChild(this); //moves this (this button) to the foreground  
}
```

Comment: That worked, you are very good at this and I feel bad that you have basically built this entire thing for me!

Comment: Actually, it only works when I add the one line, when I add a second line this.addChild(Step1btn) (i need to go all the way through Step4btn) it basically negates the code and it goes back to how it originally worked. Same for the second piece of code.

Comment: After testing it a few more times it only seems to work on the last piece of code. So once I get to setChildIndex(Step4btn,numChildren - 1); That one works, but Step0 -Step3 all still display underneath the other layers.

Comment: That is by design.  I was just assuming, but should clarify that the code should be run at the same time as when you expand your button (and only for that button).   So if you're using the code from the other question of yours I answered,  in the `onPress` method of your button put `parent.addChild(this)`